# Flutter: Google Sign in isn't working, how do I make it work on release mode?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have finished my application with flutter, in debug mode everything works fine but in release mode, firebase auth is not working. I generated a SHA1 for the release mode and added to firebase and as I'm release in it to the play store I also added the SHA1 that the App signing certificate provides, I then downloaded the google service json and added to my project again. After all this I did `flutter clean` and rebuilt the apk. But the app still can't pass further than the google sign in page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the necessary permissions such as Internet access added in the Manifest file?

Comment: Yes I added Internet permissions in the android manifest